# Ranking in Excel with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, I need to create a merit list of few student based on total marks (column `C`), then higher marks in math (column `B`) -

```
A        B  C   D
-------------------------
Student1 80 220 1
Student2 88 180 3
Student3 90 180 2
```

Expected merit position is given in column `D`.

I can use `RANK` function but I can only do that for one column (total number). If total number of multiple student is equal, I could not find any solution of this.

Comment: What if both the column **C** and the column **B** values are the same??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this one in **D1**

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$99,">"&C1)+1+SUMPRODUCT(--($C$1:$C$99=C1),--($B$1:$B$99>B1))
```

and then copy/fill down.
let me know if this helps.

### Explanation

Your first criteria sits in **column C**, and the second criteria sits in **Column B**. 
Basically, first it is counting the number of entries **($C$1:$C$99)** that are bigger than the entry itself **($C1)**. For the first one in the ranking, you will get **zero**, therefore you need to add **1** to each result **(+1)**.
Until here, you will get duplicate rankings if you have the same value twice. 
Therefore you need to add another argument to do some extra calculations based on the second criteria:
To resolve the tie situation, you need to [`sumproduct`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/sumproduct-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616?ui=en-US) two array formulas and add the result to the previous argument, the goal is to find the number of entries that are equal to this entry with **$C$1:$C$99=C1** and have a bigger value in the second criteria column **$B$1:$B$99>B1**:

 
 you add ***--*** to convert **`TRUE`** and **`FALSE`** to **0**s and **1**s so that you can multiply them:
`SUMPRODUCT(--($C$1:$C$99=C1),--($B$1:$B$99>B1))`

the first array is to see how many ties you have in the first criteria. And the second array is to find the number of bigger values than the entry itself.

**Note** you can add as many entries as you like to your columns, but remember to update the ranges in the formula, currently it is set to **99**, you can extend it to as many rows as you want.

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks a lot... :) It would be great if you could give a brief description of the algorithm. 


If I want to add number of another subject what will be the formula?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a *helper* column will provide a quick and calculation-efficient solution. Adding the math marks to the total marks as a decimal should produce a number that will rank according to your criteria. In an unused column to the right, use this formula in row 2,

```
=C2+B2/1000
```

Fill down as necessary. You can now use a conventional [RANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rank-function-cbb7d192-4c6d-4a1e-a826-c5102507122c) on this *helper* column like `=RANK(D2, D$2:D$9)` for your ranking ordinals.

Comment: If I just add tow column and apply rank function it gives the expected result. Here why you divide B2 by 1000? What is difference between this and directly adding B2 (D2=C2+B2). 

What if I need to add another subject?

Comment: Simply adding the two columns will produce the correct result *in some circumstances*, not all. You want the highest priority (aka *primary key*) on the Total column and the Math Marks should only be used as a *secondary key* in a tie. What is Student4 has a total of *210* with Math Marks of *95*? That would rank him/her above Student1 and that contradicts what I have interpreted your criteria as.

Comment: If you need another subject, add that third *key* into the previous total as a smaller fraction that will not interfere with the secondary key's role as a deciding criteria. Do you teach math?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple (or, at least, much more simpler that the one provided by the *best answer*) 'math' solution: do a linear combination with weights.
Do something like

```
weighted_marks = 10*colC + colB
```

then sort weighted marks using simple rank function.

It does solve your problem, bulding the ranking you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to limit the number of rows or the numbers used in the criteria, [Jeeped's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142874/4586966) can be extended. You can use the following formulas in cells D2 to L2, assuming that there are three criteria, the first one in column A, the second one in column B, and the third one in column C:

```
=RANK($A2,$A:$A,1)
=RANK($B2,$B:$B,1)
=D2*2^27+E2
=RANK(F2,F:F,1)
=RANK($C2,$C:$C,1)
=G2*2^27+H2
=RANK(I2,I:I,1)
=J2*2^27-ROW()
=RANK(K2,K:K,0)
```

The formulas have to be copied down. The result is in column L. Ties are broken using the row number.

If you like to add a fourth criterion, you can do the following after having the formulas above in place:

1. Add the new criterion between columns C and D.
2. Insert three new columns between columns I and J.
3. Copy columns G:I to the new columns J:L.
4. Copy column G to column M, overwriting its content.
5. Change the formula in column L to point to the new criterion.

The factor `2^27` used in the formulas balances the precision of 53 bits available in [double-precision numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). This is enough to cover the row limit of current versions of Excel.